# basic_string.h Assertion '!empty()' failed

Tags: c++, string, c++14, std, assertion

Just recompiled an older program of mine that used to run fine.
However, now it almost immediately crashes on the following code:

```
std::ifstream ifs(path);
std::string line;
while (std::getline(ifs, line))
{
    if (line.front() == '#') // crash
        continue;
    //...
}
```

The crash message is:

> /usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1280: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::front() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; reference = char&]: Assertion '!empty()' failed.

What I tried so far:

- Compiling with GCC11 instead of 12.
- Setting `-U_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -U_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`

What changed? Was I doing something wrong all along?

Comment: Apparently, the file contains some blank lines. `line.front()` exhibits undefined behavior when `line` is an empty string. Yes, this piece of code was wrong all along.

Comment: Right.  `if( line.empty() || line.front() == '#' )` will fix it.

Comment: The code also doesn't check to see if it succeeded in opening the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think it gives that error because you are trying to access `line.front()` even though it's empty. I had that bug before and checking if the string was empty or not seemed to solve it.

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs(path);
std::string line;
while (std::getline(ifs, line))
{
    if (!line.empty())
    if (line.front() == '#')
        continue;
    //...
}
```